# ActionScript3 Stop Sound On ROLL_OUT

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Im trying to make a simple interactive flash animation so when you roll over a invisible button a sound plays from the library, then when you roll out the sound stops.

So far i have this

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

stop();

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,playSound);
function playSound(event:Event) {
var mySound:elmosample = new elmosample();
var myCahnnel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();
}`
```

Is there a way to stop the sound playing with ROLL_OUT or stop the current sound when a new one starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe write a function on roll out ? 
something like

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,stopSound);

and with only playing one song at one time 
maybe put your sound variable name into one array 
and only use one channel ?
but I am not sure how you play a new sound 
so I can't give you a clear answer

hope this helps

Comment: I wrote a new function

    button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,stopSound);
    function stopSound(event:Event) {
 var mySound:elmosample1 = new elmosample1();
 var myCahnnel:SoundChannel = mySound.stop();
 
    }

but now get a output error

TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
 at _fla::MainTimeline/stopSound()

Comment: you can't use sound class to stop a sound in AS3 use its channel, so try MyChannel.stop();

this seems to be a good tut: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

stop();

var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut);   

function onRollOver(e:Event):void 
{
  //stop previous sounds
  if(myChannel)
    myChannel.stop();

  mySound = new elmosample();
  myChannel = mySound.play();
}

function onRollOut(e:Event):void
{
  myChannel.stop();
}
```